# How can i get the same value from same table?

Tags: mysql

Hey guys I have a long table in my Database and i want select all records that have the same id and parent_id.

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | lorem | 2 |

Second case:

In the second case there are ids and parent_ids in different rows.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear, You want select all record have the same value at ID column and parent_id column?

Comment: @xuanhungNguyen yes

Comment: In words, you need in "Select all columns from table where id is equal to parent_id". Now you need only to replace "all columns" with according SQL term which is an asterisk, and replace verbal "is equal to" with according operator, and you obtain the query which you need in: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = parent_id".

Comment: thanks. How kann i get id and parent_id, when they are not at the same row? for example id=2 is in the first row and parent_id=2 is in the third row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,
       PARENT_ID 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE ID=PARENT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this structure:

```
SELECT [column list] FROM [tablename] WHERE id=parent_id
```

Comment: Sq. brackets are incorrect in MySQL.

Comment: Your can change [column list] to * or id, parent_id. [tablename] is your table you want to select

Comment: The question is tagged as [mysql] - so you'd use MySQL syntax in the answer.. for the question tagged with generic [sql] your answer 'd safe.

Comment: here is sample :) SELECT * FROM abc WHERE id=parent_id

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to put an `=` sign for the column that you want to have the same values. Passing this condition to the `where` clause will filter the rows  to show only the ones where the two columns are equal.

```
select * from <your_table_name> where id = parent_id
```

- <your_table_name> = pass your table name

for your case 2 where you want the rows that matches the id = parent_id but they are not in the same row:

- you need a self-join

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
    <table_name> as t1
INNER JOIN <table_name> as t2
on t1.id = t2.parent_id
```

if in different tables:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE parent_id in (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

Comment: thanks. How kann i get id and parent_id, when they are not at the same row? for example id=2 is in the first row and parent_id=2 is in the third row.

Comment: They are not in the same row but they are in the same table. I found the answer: SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE parent_id in (SELECT id FROM table1)

Comment: @user16846263 i have adjusted the code, please upvote / accept the answer if it is working